# Using both moderated and unmoderated Usability Testing in one research

Tags: usability-testing, testing

I'm currently doing a research on a certain feature of my product. But due to the limited time I have, I only have like 2 usability testing participants who are able to meet face-to-face to do this. So I am considering to conduct a unmoderated usability testing with other participants who are willing to join but can not be in the time and place I provide (or rather have).

My question is, is it possible if I mix these two methods into one research? Even with the exact same scenario I've prepared?

Thankyou for your kindness in providing me more information about it.

Answer (score 3):

If I were in this position, I might try treating the two in-person participants as a pilot. Do a study with them, and *after* you analyze the results, you'll be able to do a higher-quality remote study because:

- You won't need to test around certain areas if you already have a plan in place based on the in-person study
- You'll ask more focused questions that are less-likely to be misinterpreted.
- You'll discover new issues or areas you want to ask about.